# AutoMapper 8 Upgrade ConstructUsing

Tags: automapper, automapper-8

I have just upgraded to v8 of AutoMapper and the expression below fails but I really cannot see why.

```
cfg.CreateMap<string, Nmtoken>()
    .ConstructUsing(i => new Nmtoken(i))                
    .ForMember(m => m.Token, o => o.MapFrom(s => s));
```

I believe that the passed expressions are valid. I get no build errors and intellisense is happy. But I get runtime error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 
'AutoMapper.IMappingExpression`2<!0,!1> 
AutoMapper.IMappingExpression`2.ConstructUsing(System.Func`2<!0,!1>)'.'
```

I'm happy to admit that I don't understand the error message.

Comment: is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies. I have two projects linked with a dependency and one of them was still using AutoMapper 7.

Answer (score 1):

I had the samme issue, but i was using AutoMapper v8.0.0.
Upgrading to version v8.1.0 solved the issue.